# Find frame of UIView of UITableViewCell after UITableViewScrollPosition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

So I do this to program a scroll in my table view controller to my first cell.

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                             animated:YES];
```

Then I want to fetch the new frame of this view:

```
 NSArray *a=[self.tableView visibleCells];
UIView *view = [a firstObject];
```

However, the frame that this view gives me (which is the first one in my array of cells) returns the position before the scroll occurred.

I have tried putting it in an animation block to make sure it has finished scrolling before it tries to find it's position

Answer (score 1):

The frame is always related to the super view. If you are interested then debug (or print out) what the super view of the cell view is. It is not directly the table view. (Used to be until iOS 7 or 8 or so but now it is embedded in some view object that scrolls along with the cell.)

You could try fetching the frame of its super view. 
However, you'd be saver comparing the origin of the cell with the base view (`self.view` from the `UIViewController`'s point of view which is the `UITableView` in case of a standard `UITableViewController`). For doing so you can use the `convertPoint:fromView` or `convertPoint:toView` methods.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it is because I had it wrapped in an animation within an animation and so the SECOND animation wasn't completing before it checked for the frame:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
                [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                             animated:NO];

            }completion:^(BOOL finished)
            {
                 NSArray *a=[self.tableView visibleCells];
                InstructionView *iv = [[InstructionView alloc] initWithTargetView:[a firstObject] andInstructionType:kNeedYouInstruction];
                iv.delegate = self;
                [iv show];
            }];
```

changing the second animation to NO stopped my problem :D